# How to encrypt large files using SynCrypto?

Tags: delphi, encryption, freepascal, delphi-10.3-rio, mormot

SynCrypto is an open source data encryption library for Delphi and FPC included in [SynPDF](https://github.com/synopse/SynPDF).

I use this code for file encryption:

```
var
  inputfile : RawByteString;
  outputfile: RawByteString;
begin
  inputfile := StringFromFile('c:\test1.mp4');
  outputfile := TAESCFB.SimpleEncrypt(inputfile,'TEST',true,true);
  FileFromString(outputfile,'c:\test2.mp4');
end;
```

However it doesn't work for large files (>1GB). Is there any way to encrypt large files?

Comment: What "doesn't work?"  What error are you getting?  Where in the code is the error happening?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: Obviously, loading a 1GB file into memory at one time is not a good idea. By the time `FileFromString()` is called, you are using 2+GB of memory. You need to read and encrypt the file in small chunks instead. I was going to suggest using `SimpleEncryptFile()`, until I saw it is doing the exact same thing internally that you are doing, so that is not helpful. So you are just going to have to do the chunking manually, using the appropriate `Encrypt...()` method for each chunk. The `SimpleEncrypt...()` methods are not going to cut it for this large of data.

Comment: It's a mistake to use strings as your buffer and a mistake to put the entire file in memory. Process the file in chunks as Remy says.

Comment: Thank you all. I got the point.

Comment: Search for  methods that take a tstream.